# What happens if the windings of a transformer are connected to each other?

Tags: transformer

What happens if one of the poles of the primary winding of a transformer is connected to one of the poles of the secondary winding of said transformer, such that electricity

1. leaves the power source,
2. enters one of the poles of the primary winding,
3. passes through the primary winding,
4. exits the primary winding at its other pole,
5. passes through the connecting wire to one pole of the secondary winding,
6. passes through the secondary winding,
7. exits the secondary winding at its other pole,
8. passes through a resistor of some sort (to keep this from just being a short circuit),
9. returns to the power source?

Yes, I *have* read [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/205196/what-happens-if-the-primary-and-secondary-side-of-a-transformer-are-short-circui).  That one describes an isolation transformer shorted at each end, so that electricity can simply bypass the transformer; my question is about a transformer wired in such a way that electricity is forced to pass through *both* windings, one after the other.

Comment: Can you provide a schematic illustrating what you described?

Comment: Depending on primary to secondary phasing, what I think you described is known as a buck or boost transformer; it either subtracts or adds voltage from/to the primary source.

Comment: Congratulations, you've invented the autotransformer.

Comment: Connecting the two windings of a transformer in series would give you a crude version of an [autotransformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autotransformer).

Comment: I'm not sure the topology the OP indicated will bring an autotransformer. The whole thing will end up in being a bipole. It looks like all he's got is an inductance, in series with the load resistor. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33860/how-do-i-use-a-transformer-as-an-inductor

Comment: @Sean. **Please provide a diagram** or you will get no written answer. We *think* we know of what you speak, but we are not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you described sounds like one of the two transformer-as-inductor connections shown below and in [How do I use a transformer as an inductor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33860/how-do-i-use-a-transformer-as-an-inductor).

It could also be an autotransformer boost or buck connection shown below.

Dots designate start of winding.

[image]
.

Comment: Ah, thanx - that clears it up.  What I was thinking of was either of the two diagrams on the left.  So, basically, I'd just have a big inductor?

Comment: Yes that is what you have.